# MySQL query optimization: UNION with rand()

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
    (SELECT ad_code, ad_zone FROM on_ads WHERE ad_zone = 1 AND status = '1' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) UNION (SELECT ad_code, ad_zone FROM on_ads WHERE ad_zone = 2 AND status = '1' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1);
```

It's being logged as slow query in my server. I am trying to optimize it. I tried the following query

```
    (SELECT ad_code, ad_zone FROM on_ads WHERE ad_zone = 1 AND status = '1' OR ad_zone = 2 AND status = '1' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2)
```

But the problem with this query is that the first one was selecting two random rows, one with ad_zone=1 and the other with ad_zone=2. While mine selects two rows, but there is no guarantee it will select two different rows (One with ad_zone=1 and the other with ad_zone=2).
What should I do to optimize this query?

Comment: If you just run them separately, is it still being logged as slow?  Perhaps the order randomly is taking too long, and it may be better to return all the data, then randomly pick one of the rows in each case.

Answer (score 0):

You have to try something like that:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT(ad_code), ad_zone FROM on_ads WHERE (ad_zone = 1 OR ad_zone = 2) AND status = '1' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2)
```

Comment: Your query has the same problem as mine. There is no guarantee it will select two different rows (One with ad_zone=1 and the other with ad_zone=2).

Comment: I believe he wants one from each case, and yours won't guarantee that.  I had thought of this and had to reject it.

Comment: you can use DISTINCT keyword for any unique value column or primary key!!

Comment: Yes or any other unique value column ir primary key column